# Ссылка на первого родителя SCSS

Tags: css, scss

В SCCS есть  [ссылка на родителя](https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/rasshirenie_css/ssilka_na_roditelya_selektora.html)

Как сделать сссылку на первого ближайшего родителя

SCSS

```
.checkbox {
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .checkbox-label {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 12px;

        &:before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"]:checked + & {

            &:before {
                background-color: #0066cc;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На выходе получается CSS

```
 .checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
 }

 .checkbox .checkbox-label {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-size: 12px;
 }

 .checkbox .checkbox-label:before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        margin-right: 5px;
 }

 input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkbox .checkbox-label:before {
        background-color: #0066cc;
 }
```

Почему не применятся нужный стиль или как сделать **&**  как ссылка на первого ближайшего родителя?

но стоит сделать строчку

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkbox-label:before {
        background-color: #0066cc;
 }
```

и стиль начинает работать

пример [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/axjcvagt/)

Comment: стиль не применяется, потому что так работает селектор `+`.

Comment: как тогда сделать ссылку на первый родитель?

Comment: возможно никак, потому что при `&` вставляется **полный** путь. Но возможно что-то можно в справке найти или какое-нибудь расширение использовать

Comment: [Sass ampersand, select immmediate parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17833674/2881286)

Comment: Приведите пример скомпилированого селектора, который Вы хотите получить в результате.

Comment: @YozhEzhi, _input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .checkbox-label:before_, так как в ней все работает

Comment: @Grundy понял. на сколько мне известно - с помощью `&` так не получится. @ruslik придётся разделить стили.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А может всё-таки немного БЭМа?

```css
.checkbox {
  &__input {
    display: none;
  }

  /*
     формируем БЭМ-элементы при помощи &
     получаем .checkbox__input
  */

  &__label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 12px;

    /*
      получаем .checkbox__label и т. д.
    */

    &:before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      margin-right: 5px;

      .checkbox__input:checked + & {
        background-color: #0066cc;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Пример на кодпене](http://codepen.io/sandmanisdancing/pen/yMEqBm).

Comment: было бы неплохо добавить объяснения в оба ответа что происходит

Comment: добавил немного комментариев

Comment: ну вы просто сделали родителем класс checkbox-label - с таким же успехом можно вытащить весь код внутри класcа  checkbox наружу

Comment: @ruslik так может быть, так и стоит делать, а не использовать множество вложенностей? Проблема, которую вы решаете, получилась именно из-за этого, потому я и предлагаю бороться не со следствием, а с причиной.

Comment: множество это когда больше 3. В моем примере уровень вложенности максимум 4, в итоговом css получается выборка не больше 2 классов

Answer (score 1):

Или вот есть рабочий метод, но делать так я не рекомендую никому.

```css
.checkbox {
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
  }

  .checkbox-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 12px;

    &:before {
      content: '';
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      margin-right: 5px;

      $a: str-insert(#{&}, " +", 10);
      /* 
         добавляем в селектор & ' +'  и записываем это в переменную $a. 
         получаем селектор .checkbox + .checkbox-label:before
      */                              

      $b: selector-replace(#{$a}, '.checkbox', 'input[type=checkbox]:checked');
      /*
         заменяем при помощи функции selector-replace
         ".checkbox" на "input[type=checkbox]:checked"
         получаем селектор input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox-label:before
      */

      @at-root #{$b}:before {
        background-color: #0066cc;
      }
      /*
        чтобы избежать наследования селекторов используем @at-root 
        и помещаем туда наш получившийся селектор
      */
    }
  }
}
```

[Пример на кодпене](http://codepen.io/sandmanisdancing/pen/LWrBXm).